What is truth of life?
I always wonder about this what is truth of our existence and everything. Why are we born, why do we die, what happens when someone dies, what is purpose of life... And so on.  And why am I even wondering about this ?

I think this question somewhat lacks focus -- it feels like it's touching on a lot of different questions but doesn't settle on any of them

Welcome to the site! See the tour & on-topic. Other similar questions: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/12666/what-is-the-meaning-of-meaning-of-life-and-why-do-people-seek-it https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/why-do-we-exist? If you feel that your question is distinct, you can edit it to ask a more focused question. Feel free to ask on Meta or in the Chat if you'd like advice on editing it

The only reason we exist is to make (presumably) improved copies of ourselves, and then fall over dead. That's the true answer to your question.

I didn't downvote because I don't really know what a good answer to this question would be, but I don't agree with the answer: you seem to equate "how we came to be here" with "what we should do about it" without explaining why those two things should be the same

@BenMillwood The OP asked, "Why are we born, why do we die, what happens when someone dies, what is purpose of life?" == My answer was the correct one for 3 of those 4, and the other question was about life after death. == The OP also asked, "what is truth of our existence and everything?" == The answer to that is 42.

@BenMillwood > you confuse  "how we came to be here" with "what we should do about it" == OP didn't ask what to do about it, he asked why are we here? What's our purpose? My answer was the correct one.

@MissUnderstands I'm not downvoting but fwiw: I don't upvote/downvote for "truth" (since there's thousands of years of disagreement on this), I upvote/downvote for whether the answer displays effort, clear argumentation, and preferably, an explanation of the history/assumptions/citations for the argument. e.g. I think "there is no purpose but things that are best at self-replication tend to stay around, so we have an impulse to self-replicate our genes and ideas" could be the core of a longer answer that i'd happily upvote, but on it's own i don't think it's very good.

@Kaia Thank you for explaining it. I don't understand these things automatically like everybody else does. I assumed everyone was familiar with the evolutionary biology, but apparently not. Or at least, I have to explain evolutionary biology in an answer that refers to it. Okay, fair enough.
